# Crash on getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-widget

I have a widget with a button that enables the camera service.

It works quite well but after some time (maybe with the home screen app exit) it loses the status (bein on or off).

I have a crash with a `NullPointerException` from, I believe, `Context.CAMERA_SERVICE`. It is really hard to reproduce and so far I haven't found the sequence that leads to the crash.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:714)
            at com.widget.tst.Widget.CallbackWidgetService.isCameraInUse(CallbackWidgetService.java:163)
            at com.widget.tst.Widget.CallbackWidgetService.startCameraInUse(CallbackWidgetService.java:242)
            //** button click--> 
 at com.widget.tst.Widget.CameraWidgetReceiver.updateWidgetButton(CameraWidgetReceiver.java:55)
            at com.widget.tst.Widget.CameraWidgetReceiver.onReceive(CameraWidgetReceiver.java:32)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3632)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source:0) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1975) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7367) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
```

How can `Context.CAMERA_SERVICE` be null?

```
    private void isCameraInUse(){
            if(context == null) return;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
-->  line 163       mCameraManager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "You need to run Android version "+
                                Build.VERSION_CODES.M+" or above",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
```

Comment: try to change `mCameraManager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);` to `mCameraManager = (CameraManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);`

Comment: your context is null you are calling `isCameraInUse` from wrong place. for example from another thread. you have called `isCameraInUse` when activity or fragment that contains this method (and they are the context for this method) is destroyed

Comment: @Vladyslav: I'll try but don't you believe it is Context.CAMERA_SERVICE that is null. How can context.getSystemService will make a change?

Comment: @wizard. context can't be null?

Comment: `Context.CAMERA_SERVICE` is not null. Your stacktrace says that the object, on which you are calling this method is null, not the argument of the method

Comment: Good point. It is taking time for the problem to occur. Thanks!

Comment: @narb you are wrong context could be null when it is destroyed for example an Activity has its own context when Activity is destroyed its context is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like somewhere inside your current class (`this`) it's own context gets nulled, and that's why you get your NPE.

But since you have a 100% non-null context in a variable (`if(context == null) return;`), why don;t you use it instead of `this`'s own context?:

```
mCameraManager = (CameraManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
```